# SCANPST.EXE Missing Repair Button

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

Whenever I try opening outlook, I get this series of popups:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, in the last popup I'm just stuck. There is no repair button. (clicking OK just closes the popup and seems to do nothing)

I've tried

- reinstalling Office entirely
- running sfcscan /now
- running as admin
- deleting 'Internet Calendar Subscriptions.pst'

None of these have any effect at all, apart from deleting the pst, which causes the SCANPST tool to complain that it can't find the pst...

I also tried renaming SCANPST.EXE to SCANPST.OLD and repairing outlook, but Outlook no longer appears on progams and features?

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: It's SCANPST.EXE not PSTSCAN.EXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/56d2aa8f-449c-434a-abac-356d69ac12f8/microsoft-outlook-365-something-is-wrong-with-one-of-your-data?forum=outlook

Is this the same issue as you? If so, please check the workarounds mentioned in this thread and see if your issue could be resloved.

Comment: Following the steps given in the answer seems to have fixed the issue.  I can now open Outlook normally and see all my emails

Comment: I have this same issue, but the link you put as the answer to this question just shows Page Not Found. :(